# How to get jQuery to cycle through multiple groups of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, I don't know much about javascript and have been relying on Google to help me get through. I'm working on a design element where I have a several headlines and subtitles which need to cycle through in sync (so headline 1 goes with subtitle 1.)

I found this codepen (https://codepen.io/maaviles/pen/olKxr)

```
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

(function cycle() { 

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(1000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

This works fine for either the headings or the subheadings but not both. All of my fiddling with it has either broken the script or caused the animation to muddle up the headings with the subheadings. I need to use divs because the actual text is being pulled from text files.

When I originally posted this question, I was met with the response that I should post my code. However, it was part of a much longer page. So I've created my own codepen with just the elements we're looking at with some of the formatting thrown in.

My pen can be found at https://codepen.io/raining_hail/pen/aEBqKj

To clarify, I need to get the headings to cycle through like the subheadings.

Comment: *(so headline 1 goes with subtitle 1.)* where is the part in your code which refers to headline and subtitle?  provide your code and explain what exactly not working for you

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity and added a codepen link to put what I'm working on into context.

Comment: Please read the "*[mcve]*" guidelines: we expect your (relevant) code to be *in* your question, otherwise your code can, potentially, be removed or become otherwise inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: you need to add the next code to css to hide all divs on default

```
div[id^="subtitle-"] , div[id^="content-"]{
  display : none;
}
```

2nd: you need to make `cycle` as a function .. enough one function for both .. pass `elements , i` as an argument like that  .. `elements` for elements and `i` for index of the element you need to start with .. in your case use `0`to start from the first element

```
function cycle(el , i) {
  //alert(i);
  el
    .hide()
    .eq(i)
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(400, function(){
      i = ++i % el.length;
      cycle(el , i);
    });
}
```

Now you can run the function when document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var divs = $('div[id^="subtitle-"]');
  cycle(divs , 0);
  var titles = $('div[id^="content-"]');
  cycle(titles , 0);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var divs = $('div[id^="subtitle-"]');
  cycle(divs , 0);
  var titles = $('div[id^="content-"]');
  cycle(titles , 0);
});

function cycle(el , i) {
  //alert(i);
  el
    .hide()
    .eq(i)
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(400, function(){
      i = ++i % el.length;
      cycle(el , i);
    });
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Annie+Use+Your+Telescope");

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Annie Use Your Telescope", cursive;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.topbox {width: 500px;
  height: 62px;
margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: #cf3d6a;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 
    1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
    1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 
    1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  overflow:
}

.subheading {
  text-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
    1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


div[id^="subtitle-"] , div[id^="content-"]{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topbox">
<div id="content-1" class="heading">Test Heading #1</div>
<div id="content-2" class="heading">Test Heading #2</div>
<div id="content-3" class="heading">Test Heading #3</div>
  <div id="content-4" class="heading">Test Heading #4</div></div>

<div class="box">
  <div id="subtitle-1" class="subheading animated rubberBand">Test Subheading #1</div>
  <div id="subtitle-2" class="subheading animated rubberBand">Test Subheading #2</div>
  <div id="subtitle-3" class="subheading animated rubberBand">Test Subheading #3</div>
  <div id="subtitle-4" class="subheading animated rubberBand">Test Subheading #4</div>
</div>
```

Note: you can use this function to use it with another elements by call `cycle(element , 0)` to start from 0 element

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
  i = 0;
(function cycle() {
  divs
    .eq(i)
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(400, cycle);
  i = ++i % divs.length;
})();
var divs1 = $('div[id^="subtitle-"]').hide(),
  i = 0;
(function cycle() {
  divs1
    .eq(i)
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(400, cycle);
  i = ++i % divs1.length;
})();
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Works perfectly and I can see where I was going wrong.